# Convert method to `System.Delegate` to get `MethodInfo` for action name?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, delegates

I am trying to convert a method to a `System.Delegate`:

```
Delegate method = (Delegate)MyMethod;
```

But that does not work as I get an exception telling me `MyMethod` can't be converted to the non-delegate type.

**How can I get a generic `System.Delegate` from a method?**

Purpose is to get the `MethodInfo.Name` of the method. So I basically want to get the method name as a string "in a strongly-typed fashion". I want to create a helper for MVC like the following:

```
protected internal RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction(Func<ActionResult> action)
{ 
    return RedirectToAction(action.Method.Name);
}
```

then I can call e.g. `return RedirectToAction(Index);` instead of `return RedirectToAction("Index")` and so see references for `Index` and have compile-time check if the action exists. But the helper code above only works for parameter-less actions, so I would like this to work for actions with any kind of parameters without the need to specify an overload for every possible parameter constellation.

Comment: I'm not sure you can get a method name from an Func<> it would need to be an Expression<Func<>>. There are lots of example to get a name from an Expression.

Comment: @CharlesNRice: Yes, you can. The `RedirectToAction` example above does work fine with parameter-less actions. At the moment I am duplicating this code which different `Func` parameters to get it working for all my actions, but I would like to avoid that with a "generic delegate"...

Answer (score 1):

Use Delegate.CreateDelegate

```
Func<string, string> funcToConvert = testMethod;

var del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(funcToConvert.GetType(), funcToConvert.Method);
var name = del.Method.Name;
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but that does not help in my case as I still need the "custom" `Func`. And if I already have `funcToConvert.Method` I do not need anything else, as the `Method` is the thing I need...

Comment: What do you have?  You could use reflection to get the methodinfo and type and still create the delegate

Comment: `MethodInfo` is what I need. My target is to be able to call `RedirectToAction(Index)` where `Index` can be any method with any kind of parameters and inside my `RedirectToAction` overload I can get or directly have the `MethodInfo` of the method supplied as a parameter...

Comment: MVC uses reflection usually to go from string to method. Usually the action is the method name or a method that is decorated with an attribute.  I'm not clear on how your usage differs

Comment: The difference is I do not want to use a string but the strongly-typed method itself. This has two benefits: I see where the method is used in code (e.g. it shows up in the "References" CodeLens) and the compiler already checks if the method exists and you get a compiler-error when you try to redirect to a non-existent action...